# In a Reactor Netty HttpClient/HttpServer configuration, I am not able to get the retrieve the request object on a post to the Server

Tags: java, netty, reactor-netty

A Reactor-Netty HttpClient is sending a request, HttpClientRequest, to an HttpServer. On the server side, I am not able to get the request object out of the HttpServerRequest. I can retreive the FluxByteBuf from the HttpServerRequest, but not the ByteBuf object in the Flux object. Typically, subscribing to the Flux would allow me to get the request object, but that is not working here. The response back from the server is being received by the client successfully. Does anyone know why subscribing to a Flux/Mono would not work on the server side of a Reactor-Netty client/server?

The client code is:

```
public class Client {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Client.class.getSimpleName());

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        Consumer<byte[]> onSuccess = (byte[] response) -> {
            ElectionResponse electionResponse = SerializationUtils.deserialize(response);
            log.info("response in onSuccess: "+electionResponse);

        };
        Consumer<Throwable> onError = (Throwable ex) -> {
            ex.getMessage();
        };

        Runnable onCompletion = () -> {
            System.out.println("Message Completed");

        };
        ElectionRequest electionRequest = new ElectionRequest("aRequest");
        byte[] requestBytes = SerializationUtils.serialize(electionRequest);
        ByteBuf requestByteBuf = Unpooled.copiedBuffer(requestBytes);

        HttpClient.create()
                .tcpConfiguration(tcpClient -> tcpClient.host("10.0.0.19"))
                .port(61005)
                .post()
                .uri("/echo")
                .send(Mono.just(requestByteBuf))
                .responseContent()
                .aggregate()
                .asByteArray()
                .subscribe(onSuccess, onError, onCompletion);

        try {
            Thread.sleep(15000);
        } catch(InterruptedException ie) {
            ie.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The server code is:

```
public class Server {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getSimpleName());

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ElectionResponse electionResponse = new ElectionResponse("aResponse");
        byte[] responseArray = SerializationUtils.serialize(electionResponse);

        Consumer<ByteBuf> onSuccess = (ByteBuf request) -> {
            System.out.println("onSuccess: Request received!");
        };
        Consumer<Throwable> onError = (Throwable ex) -> {
            ex.getMessage();
        };
        Runnable onCompletion = () -> {
            System.out.println("Message Completed");

        };

        DisposableServer server =
            HttpServer.create()
                      .host("10.0.0.19")
                      .port(61005)
                      .route(routes ->
                          routes
                            .post("/echo",
                                (request, response) -> {
                                    request.receive().retain().next().subscribe(onSuccess, onError, onCompletion);
                                    return response.send(Mono.just(Unpooled.copiedBuffer(responseArray).retain()));
                                                       }
                                    ))
                        .bindNow();

        server.onDispose()
                .block();
    }
}
```

The environment and maven dependencies are as follows:

```
Apache Maven 3.6.1
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 11.0.6, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: /home/linuxlp/opt/graalvm/graalvm-svm-linux-20.1.0-ea+28
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "5.3.0-51-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-netty</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.reactivestreams</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactive-streams</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.3</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Can you explain more about this `I am not able to get the request object out of the HttpServerRequest`. The provided HttpServerRequest contains everything that you may need like method, uri, headers etc. and also with `receive` you have the body.

Comment: Did you check https://projectreactor.io/docs/netty/release/reference/index.html#_consuming_data_3

Comment: The client sends a request, an HttpClientRequest, that is received at the server as an HttpServerRequest. The HttpServerRequest contains a ByteBufFlux object. In this case when the ByteBuf object in the Flux publisher is deserialized back to the domain object of type ElectionRequest (see the Client code provided earlier). It is this domain object, ElectionRequest, I am trying to get from the HttpServerRequest through a subscribe method. In the client code it is the object requestByteBuf that is sent to the server through a Mono publisher.

Answer (score 0):

What do you think about composing the request/response like this

```
public class Server {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getSimpleName());

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Consumer<byte[]> onSuccess = (byte[] request) -> {
            System.out.println("onSuccess: Request received!");
        };
        Consumer<Throwable> onError = (Throwable ex) -> {
            ex.getMessage();
        };
        Runnable onCompletion = () -> {
            System.out.println("Message Completed");

        };

        DisposableServer server =
                HttpServer.create()
                        .host("10.0.0.19")
                        .port(61005)
                        .route(routes ->
                                routes.post("/echo",
                                        (request, response) ->
                                                response.send(request.receive()
                                                                     .aggregate()
                                                                     .asByteArray()
                                                                     .doOnNext(onSuccess)
                                                                     .doOnError(onError)
                                                                     .doOnTerminate(onCompletion)
                                                                     .flatMap(bytes -> {
                                                                         ElectionRequest electionRequest = (ElectionRequest) SerializationUtils.deserialize(bytes);
                                                                         ElectionResponse electionResponse = new ElectionResponse(electionRequest.getStr());
                                                                         return Mono.just(Unpooled.copiedBuffer(SerializationUtils.serialize(electionResponse)));
                                                                     }))))
                        .bindNow();

        server.onDispose()
                .block();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but when I implement it I have the same problem as when using subscribe, that is, the onSuccess in doOnNext is never invoked. As I said, on the server side, I need to get the domain request object out of the ByteBufFlux request, act on it in a service and then return a response object contained in the HttpServerResponse object. The response is working fine. When the client sends multiple requests, the client gets back the expected response(s). The problem is on the server side where the onSuccess lambda is not invoked by a subscribe or the doOnNext.

Comment: create a reproducible example and open an issue  here https://github.com/reactor/reactor-netty